# UITableView doesn't work fine when I use mask

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5

My Tableview load only 4 cells but I have 25 cells in count...The scroll from tableview scroll to 25 itens, but The cells are clear...the background from cells are white and from cell 5 to 25 are all clear color background and empty... I did put a breakpoint in [listaPins count] and really has 25 itens..

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_listaPins count];
}
```

Call only 4 times

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

**EDIT**
I did discovery that I comment this code, the tableview works fine. but whats wrong with this?

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_tbFeeds.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = _tbFeeds.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
_tbFeeds.layer.mask = maskLayer;
[maskLayer release];
```

Comment: and how big is your table view?

Comment: 300x371 position x = 10 y = 108

Comment: Possibly an issue with cell reuse.  We'd need to see your implementation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: what is your row height

Comment: I did discovery the problem but don't know how to solve this. See my edit, please

Comment: the reference from my tableview

Answer (score 0):

The code looks perfect. Please check the frame of Table at the time of masking. try to log it. Rest everything looks ok.