# Round top corners in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I did add round corner in UItableView but only in top corners.
The problem is that when I use mask in UItableView, the UItableView show only the first 4 cells.

When I comment the code from mask, the tableview works fine..

Here is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:_tbFeeds.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(9.0, 9.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = _tbFeeds.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
_tbFeeds.layer.mask = maskLayer; //tbfeeds is my tableview
[maskLayer release];
```

Comment: Looks like almost an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451438/uitableview-doesnt-work-fine-when-i-use-mask) from the same poster.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be to add a header to the tableview:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 10)]; // height of header (10)
    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // color of header (white)

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:headerView.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    maskLayer.frame = headerView.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    headerView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```